# Varnish stoped working and dies after start OK

Tags: linux, apache, caching, centos, varnish

I run varnish whit drupal, on centos. 
It worked just file, when suddenly it stopped working.
On :

> service varnish start

I get:

> Starting varnish HTTP accelerator:                         [  OK  ]

But when I check  status I get :

> varnishd dead but pid file exists

This is my deaflt.vcl:

```js
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
  .host = "mydomain.com";
  .port = "port_num";
  .connect_timeout = 3600s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 3600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 3600s;
}

# 
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
# 
 sub vcl_recv {
 
   # Add a unique header containing the client address
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
 
   # set the custom header
   if (req.http.Cookie ~ "ABtesting=B") {
  set req.http.X-ABtesting = "B";
   } else {
  set req.http.X-ABtesting = "A";
   }
 
 # do this only once per request
 if (req.restarts == 0) {
   # normalize Accept-Encoding to reduce vary
   if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
  if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE 6") {
    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
  } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
  } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
  } else {
    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
  }
   }
 }
 
 if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(Mobile|Android|iPhone|iPad)") {
   set req.http.User-Agent = "mobile";
 } else {
   set req.http.User-Agent = "desktop";
 }
 
 
     if (req.request != "GET" &&
       req.request != "HEAD" &&
       req.request != "PUT" &&
       req.request != "POST" &&
       req.request != "TRACE" &&
       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
       req.request != "DELETE") {
         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
         return (pipe);
     }
     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
         return (pass);
     }
 // Remove has_js and Google Analytics __* cookies.
 set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
 // Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
 set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
     if (req.http.Authorization /*|| req.http.Cookie*/) {
         /* Not cacheable by default */
         return (pass);
     }
     return (lookup);
 }

# 
# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pass {
#     return (pass);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hash {
#     set req.hash += req.url;
#     if (req.http.host) {
#         set req.hash += req.http.host;
#     } else {
#         set req.hash += server.ip;
#     }
#     return (hash);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     if (!obj.cacheable) {
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }
# 
 sub vcl_fetch {
   if (beresp.ttl > 0s) {
   /* Remove Expires from backend, it's not long enough */
   unset beresp.http.expires;

   /* Set the clients TTL on this object */
   set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age=900";

   /* Set how long Varnish will keep it */
   set beresp.ttl = 1w;

   /* marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age: */
   set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";
            }
 
    # vary on the custom header
   if (beresp.http.Vary) {
  set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary ", X-ABtesting";
   } else {
  set beresp.http.Vary = "X-ABtesting";
   }
     if (!beresp.cacheable) {
         return (pass);
     }
     if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
         return (pass);
     }
     return (deliver);
 }
 
 
 
# 
 sub vcl_deliver {
 if (resp.http.Vary) {
    set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "X-ABtesting", "Cookie");
 }
  if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
  /* Remove the magic marker */
  unset resp.http.magicmarker;

  /* By definition we have a fresh object */
  set resp.http.age = "0";
 }

 
     return (deliver);
 }
# 
# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} obj.status " " obj.response {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} obj.status " " obj.response {"</h1>
#     <p>"} obj.response {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} req.xid {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
```

Note that apache is listening to the port of varnish, and it was working whitout problem.

Comment: No logs, errors messages at application and-or system level, nothing?

Comment: I wish. 
when I try 'tail -f' I get 'no such file or directory'. 
I have older logs for varnish - so they worked once. 

And no error, just ok. Maybe there is another log or place I can look, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Try what is listed here: https://serverfault.com/questions/306240/where-can-i-find-varnish-log-files-var-log-varnish-is-empty and https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/debugging-varnish-vcl

Comment: Thank you, but that didnt work. 
varnishncsa (pid  2205) is running...
But nothing in logs, not varnish.log or varnishncsa.log.

Answer (score 0):

to understand why it is dying, either you have a look at your dmesg output and look for "die" or "kill" or you have a look at "varnishadm panic.show"